# Concatenate multiple from_tensor_slices() Datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use a util function from the TF Recommender System (TFRS) to turn a TF Dataset into a Listwise TF Dataset.

[sample_listwise()](https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders/blob/main/tensorflow_recommenders/examples/movielens.py#L129)

Basically, the function (above) makes X amount of lists with Y amount of random samples in each list for every user Z in the dataset. My problem is that when I pass in a TF Dataset with a few million records in it, the program crashes.

```
tensor_slices = {"user_id": [], "movie_title": [], "user_rating": []}
```

It appears, that eventually, the `tensor_slices` dict inside the function fills up with so much information that it run out of memory and crashes.

I modified the original function by turning each users sampled list into a TF dataset via the `from_tensor_slices()` method at the end of processing each user. This allowed me to not let the `tensor_slices` dict implode. I let the program loop through each user and concatenate each `from_tensor_slice()` dataset onto each other before returning a full TF Datatset.

```
def sample_listwise(
    rating_dataset: tf.data.Dataset,
    num_list_per_user: int = 50,
    num_examples_per_list: int = 5,
    seed: Optional[int] = None,
) -> tf.data.Dataset:

    random_state = np.random.RandomState(seed)

    example_lists_by_user = defaultdict(_create_feature_dict)

    movie_title_vocab = set()
    for example in rating_dataset:
        user_id = example["user_id"].numpy()
        example_lists_by_user[user_id]["movie_title"].append(example["movie_title"])
        example_lists_by_user[user_id]["user_rating"].append(example["user_rating"])
        movie_title_vocab.add(example["movie_title"].numpy())

    i = 0
    for user_id, feature_lists in example_lists_by_user.items():
        
        tensor_slices = {"user_id": [], "movie_title": [], "user_rating": []}
        
        for _ in range(num_list_per_user):

            # Drop the user if they don't have enough ratings.
            if len(feature_lists["movie_title"]) < num_examples_per_list:
                continue

            sampled_movie_titles, sampled_ratings = _sample_list(
                feature_lists,
                num_examples_per_list,
                random_state=random_state,
            )

            tensor_slices["user_id"].append(user_id)
            tensor_slices["movie_title"].append(sampled_movie_titles)
            tensor_slices["user_rating"].append(sampled_ratings)
    
        # check if all lists for a user are stored in tensor_slices
        if len(tensor_slices["user_id"]) == num_list_per_user:

            tmp_tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor_slices)
            
            # clear out tensor slice dict for that user
            tensor_slices.clear()
            
            # concat tmp_tf_dataset to the main tf dataset 
            if i == 0:
                tf_dataset = tmp_tf_dataset
            else:
                tf_dataset = tf_dataset.concatenate(tmp_tf_dataset)

            i += 1

    return tf_dataset
```

I can pass the result of this function to a model if I keep the amount of data very small (250k records). If I increase the amount of data to process.... eventually the model fails with a `Segmentation Fault` error.

So my question is, how do I properly concatenate all this data together to form one coherent dataset, so my program won't crash and I can side step the `tenor_slices` dict implosion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original function first creates `example_lists_by_user` using the input dataset, then creates `tensor_slices` object, and finally converts it to another `tf.Dataset`. It takes a dataset and returns a dataset.

If the problem arises from the size of `tensor_slices` (*and not from* `example_lists_by_user`), there is a way to avoid creating it altogether, using a generator expression and `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`.

Specifically, you could have something like:

```
def sample_listwise(...):
  # generate example_lists_by_user...

  def example_generator():
    for user_id, feature_lists in example_lists_by_user.items():
      for _ in range(num_list_per_user):
        movie_titles, ratings = _sample_list(...)
        yield {'user_id': user_id, 'movie_title': movie_titles, 'user_rating': ratings}

  # create a dataset from the generator function above
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    example_generator,
    output_signature={
      'user_id':tf.TensorSpec([], tf.string), 
      'movie_title':tf.TensorSpec([num_examples_per_list], tf.string), 
      'user_rating':tf.TensorSpec([num_examples_per_list], tf.string)
    })
```

Comment: One question, when I print the output the Tensor is `TF.Tensor(-2, shape=() ...)`. The original function produced shape `TF.Tensor(51240, shape=(), ...)`. When I try to save the model I get this error: `FailedPreconditionError: Failed to serialize the input pipeline graph: ResourceGather is stateful. [Op:DatasetToGraphV2].` I thought `unbatch()` ing the dataset would enable it to save, but I got an error. Would it be better to try to unbatch() the dataset to normal or save/load the [model weight](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-to-solve-failedpreconditionerror-in-saving-tfrs-model/6561)?